# Dense Sets in R

Tags: general-topology

I was told that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. If you add in the limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$  for the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, then that is all of $\mathbb{R}$. I was also told that $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ was dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Are the limit points of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ the points of $\mathbb{Q}$? I do not really understand why this is true.

Comment: I suppose that you mean $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$, rather than $\Bbb{R/Q}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between every two real numbers there exist a rational number; and similarly an irrational number.

Therefore, given a real number $r$ we can find a sequence of rational numbers whose limit is $r$, and at the same time a sequence of irrational numbers whose limit is $r$.

So every real number is in the closure of both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it goes both ways, you can      intuitively   think
Of $\mathbb {R} - \mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $ \mathbb{R} $ since there are more irrationals than rationals.

Comment: There are also more points in the Cantor set than points in $\Bbb Q$. And yet $\Bbb Q$ is dense, but the Cantor set is nowhere dense. Cardinality does not imply density!

Comment: Yes, but the cantor set involves removing whole intervals, so of course it could not be dense, I was just trying to give an idea of the situation, to be more exact, you can approximate a rational very closely by irrationals, just by taking a sequence of irrationals, that act "rationally" up to so many digits, and then have a completely random pattern of digits

Comment: But the idea that you seem to be giving is that any uncountable set has to be dense. This is not true, as you agree with me. Any set meeting every open interval is dense, but then again... that is the definition of being dense, so there's no new information here. (I didn't downvote, by the way.)

Comment: No worries, but clearly uncountable doesn't imply dense, since $\mathbb { Q }$ is countable and dense.

Comment: Your logic is flawed, $\text{uncountable}\implies\text{dense}$ is *not equivalent* to $\text{countable}\implies\text{not dense}$.

Comment: What I really meant was is that the irrationals and rationals are very similar in the sense that neither of them contain a whole interval, but they **almost** do, and the irrationals being dense makes sense because the rationals are dense, and they both make up for the other's "gaps" in the intervals

Comment: Yes, sorry for a second I thought you meant an if and only if statement. (very tired, have just got up)

Comment: General question: Do you think in general that if say $U\subset X$ was dense in $X$, then if we let $V=X-U$, but we know $V$ is of higher cardinality than $U$, does that imply that $V$ must be dense?

Comment: No, consider a trivial case. The topology on $\Bbb R$ defined by taking open sets as the empty set and all the sets $U$ such that $0\in U$. Then $\{0\}$ is dense, but $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not dense, because it's closed and closed sets are never dense if they are not the entire space.

Comment: Shall we consider this on another thread? As I am very interested, but do not wish to clog up this one

Comment: Perhaps. I'm going to sleep now anyway. It's time to stop being sleep deprived, and starting to sleep!